# How to create a widgets (Buttons) form Derived Class

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I' am newbie, im styding wxwidgets and c++, in this topic i want ask How to create a widgets (Buttons) form Derived Class ( APMainFrame that inherit MainFrame class)

***Code MainFrame GUI:***

```
MainFrame::MainFrame( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );
    this->SetBackgroundColour( wxSystemSettings::GetColour( wxSYS_COLOUR_WINDOWFRAME ) );
    .....
    this->SetMenuBar( m_menubar1 );
    this->Centre( wxBOTH );
}
```

***and APMainFrame.h code:***

```
class APMainFrame : public MainFrame
{
    public:
        /** Constructor */
        APMainFrame( wxWindow* parent );
    //// end generated class members
        wxButton* HelloWorld; // here i wanna create function and button for GUI
        void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
private:
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

enum
{
    BUTTON_Hello = wxID_HIGHEST + 1 
};
```

***and file APMainFrame.cpp:***

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(APMainFrame, MainFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(BUTTON_Hello, APMainFrame::OnExit) 
END_EVENT_TABLE() // The button is pressed

APMainFrame::APMainFrame( wxWindow* parent )
:
MainFrame( parent )
{
    HelloWorld = new wxButton(this, BUTTON_Hello, _T("Hello World"),
        // shows a button on this window
        wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0); 

}

void APMainFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(TRUE);
}
```

I just wanna create Widgets form Drived class.
Thanks so much.

Comment: It's really not clear what are you asking about. Your code does create a new button, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about the `wxButton` not showing up on your `wxFrame`? In addition, I would recommend you have a look at some of the wxWidgets samples, specifically the _minimal_ one...

Comment: @segmentation_fault yep it is right what i need, thanks you so much, i gonna have a look it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a panel (`wxPanel`) and a sizer to your `wxFrame` derived frame.

You have created your button, but you also need to add it to the frame so it knows to render it.

Thus, like so:

```
MainFrame( parent )
{
    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    panel->SetSizer(sizer);
    HelloWorld = new wxButton(this, BUTTON_Hello, _T("Hello World"),
        // shows a button on this window
        wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0); 

    sizer->Add(HelloWorld);
}
```

Additional helpful resources:

- [Overview of Sizers](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_sizer.html)
- [Sizers explanation with pictures](http://neume.sourceforge.net/sizerdemo/)
- wxWidgets samples